# How to sum every second digit in list - Prolog?

Tags: list, prolog, clpfd

Given some list of integers, I want to calculate the sum of every second element in the list using Prolog ?

E.g.:

```
[1,2,3,4] => [2+4] = 6
```

Comment: Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use library([aggregate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate)):

```
sum_every_nth1(L,I,S) :- aggregate(sum(X), P^(nth1(P,L,X), P mod I=:=0), S).

?- sum_every_nth1([1,2,3,4],2,S).
S = 6.
```

sum_every_nth1/3 is based on the 'relational' behaviour of nth1/3, that binds a position (P in the sample) in a list to an element. So, when called with P free, it binds it to successive indexes. The goal `P mod I=:=0` then filters out the indexes not satisfying the requirement (cause failure of the conjunction - a comma means AND).

*edit*

library(aggregate) has a specific purpose, namely to supply missing aggregation operators available in SQL. To handle multiplication, I would suggest to separate the 'fetching' of elements from the actual operation performed on them:

```
every_nth1(L,I,Ns) :- findall(X, (nth1(P,L,X),P mod I=:=0), Ns).

mul_every_nth1(L,I,M) :-
    every_nth1(L,I,[N0|Ns]),
    foldl([N,M0,M1]>>(M1 is M0*N),Ns,N0,M).
```

every_nth1/3 get a list of selected elements, foldl/4 takes care to multiply them.

```
?- mul_every_nth1([1,2,3,4],2,M).
M = 8.
```

*edit*

if you're missing library(yall):

```
multiply(N,M0,M1) :- M1 is M0*N.

mul_every_nth1(L,I,M) :-
    every_nth1(L,I,[N0|Ns]),
    foldl(multiply,Ns,N0,M).
```

Comment: library(aggregate) it's usually autoloaded, so nothing should be required. Anyway, `?-[library(aggregate)].` will load it. In a source file, use instead `:- use_module(library(aggregate)).`

Comment: Libary aggregate, in implementions SWI-Prolog ver 7.2 :))

Comment: Yes, this answer very help me :)

Comment: Im sorry how to operate mul this list ? Example 2*3*5 please

Comment: is not possible with library(aggregate), but see my edit

Comment: ymm ERROR: apply:foldl_/4: Undefined procedure: (>>)/5
   Exception: (10) >>([_G4168, _G4171, _G4174], _G4174 is _G4171*_G4168, 4, 2, _G4

Comment: I think it's because you're using a version without library(yall) available. Sorry, see my edit...

Comment: not work:1 ?- mul_every_nth1([1,2,3,4],2,M).
ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: mul_every_nth1/3 (DWIM could not correct goal)

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to accomplish this, but to give you an idea of a simple recursive solution using an accumulator to keep track of the current sum:

```
% Sets accumulator to 0 for convenience
sum_second(List,Result) :- sum_second(List,0,Result).

sum_second([],A,A).             % Empty list
sum_second([_],A,A).            % One element left in list
sum_second([_,H|T],A,R) :-      % Accumulate sum of second element
    A2 is A+H,
    sum_second(T,A2,R).
```

Example usage:

```
?- sum_second([1],R).
R = 0.
?- sum_second([1,2],R).
R = 2.
?- sum_second([1,2,3,4,5,6],R).
R = 12.
```

Comment: `?- sum_second(Ls, _, _).` shows only a single solution. Certainly we expect a bit more from a relation?

Comment: Why all the cuts? They aren't necessary and should be avoided unless there's a specific, intentional need for them. Also, you can provide a tidier, predicate to call this one: `sum_second(Ls, R) :- sum_second(Ls, 0, R).` so the caller doesn't have to provide the initial accumulator value.

Comment: What is the purpose of the operator " ! . " ?

Comment: I added the cuts to make sure termination occurred explicitly instead of leaving (redundant) choice point(s) which can be confusing for people who are just starting out in Prolog - I know it was for me. But I understand what you mean, I will remove them from the code as they are not required. As for a sum_second/2 for calling predicate, I wanted to write it, but thought it was trivial to this question. Anyways, I will amend my answer and make sure to in the future always include the 'calling' predicate for convenience. Thanks for the critique, it's always welcome.

Answer (score 3):

While the [solution by @SeekAndDestroy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37772793/4609915) is okay, I'd like to add:

1. Use [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) for declarative integer arithmetics.

   ```
   :- use_module(library(clpfd)).
   ```
2. Employ first-argument indexing to avoid useless choicepoints.

   ```
   list_evens_odds([], [], []).
   list_evens_odds([X|Xs], [X|Es], Os) :-
      list_evens_odds(Xs, Os, Es).
   ```

*That's it!*

To sum up every other item (starting with the 2nd), query like so:

```
?- list_evens_odds([1,2,3,4], _, Zs), sum(Zs, #=, Sum).
Zs = [2,4], Sum = 6.
```